# Change the permalink URL to include a taxonomy term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, urls

I'm brining 3 wordpress sites into one but our existing sites have good brand recognition in our field.  So we have the main site which is sitemain.com and all articles that were there have been copied across and have the url pattern as sitemain.com/post title.  I want to bring the content from sites 2 and 3 but keep a part of the URL to distinguish what site its from.  My initial thought was to have 3 content types,but the content structure of all the posts across the sites is the same so I would rather have a single post type and use taxonomies to differentiate them.  I've created a taxonomy called section with the options site1, site2 and site3.  They can only pick one.

Is it possible to alter the URL of the post to be sitename.com/site1/post title or sitename.com/site2/post etc title using taxonomies?

Thanks

Kieran